# Left Join in HQL - Hibernate query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

I have 2 entites , each stored in mysql table. 
1. productA : {productId(pk) , desc , date}
2. productB : {productId(pk) , quantity,type,date}

I want to run this SQL query:

> 

```
     select a.* 
     from productA a left join productB b using(productId)   
     where b.productId is null
```

(return all the products from a that not exists in b)

Is it possible to write this query in Hibernate?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to write this query in Hibernate?

Yes, of course. From [JPA specification 2.1 (4.4.5.2 Left Outer Joins)](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html):

> LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are synonymous. They enable the
>   retrieval of a set of entities where matching values in the join
>   condition may be absent. The syntax for a left outer join is
>
> ```
> LEFT [OUTER] JOIN join_association_path_expression [AS] identification_variable
> [join_condition]
> ```
>
> An outer join without a specified join condition has an implicit join
>   condition over the foreign key relationship corresponding to the
>   join_association_path_expression. It would typically be mapped to a
>   SQL outer join with an ON condition on the foreign key relationship as
>   in the queries below: **Java Persistence query language**:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN s.products p
> GROUP BY s.name
> ```
>
> **SQL**:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p.id)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Products p
> ON s.id = p.supplierId
> GROUP By s.name
> ```
>
> An outer join with an explicit ON condition would cause an additional
>   specified join condition to be added to the generated SQL: **Java
>   Persistence query language:**
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN s.products p
> ON p.status = 'inStock'
> GROUP BY s.name
> ```
>
> **SQL**:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p.id)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN Products p
> ON s.id = p.supplierId AND p.status = 'inStock'
> GROUP BY s.name
> ```
>
> Note that the result of this query will be different from that of the
>   following query:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.name, COUNT(p)
> FROM Suppliers s LEFT JOIN s.products p
> WHERE p.status = 'inStock'
> GROUP BY s.name
> ```
>
> The result of the latter query will exclude suppliers who have no
>   products in stock whereas the former query will include them.
>
> An important use case for LEFT JOIN is in enabling the prefetching of
>   related data items as a side effect of a query. This is accomplished
>   by specifying the LEFT JOIN as a FETCH JOIN as described below.